# Is there a way to make a list of abbreviations and have excel pull from that list to return the non-shortened form?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working with a dataset involving samples taken from various sites. Each sample has a unique identification code(UID) with a two-letter code that corresponds to the location, followed by the date they were collected. It looks something like this: BA_230808, where "BA" stands for "Banff"

I have a list of UIDs and need to enter their site location as part of data reporting. There are 14 sites in total.   Is there a way for me to make a dataset/list of what each abbreviation stands for and have a function pull from it, so if I input the UID excel automatically return the location as a text string?

The only progress I've made so far is using the LEFT function to extract the location code. In my mind, the last resort would be to just use a bunch of if-statements.

Comment: No bunch of `IF()` statements, since you have a very less site totals like only `14` create a table of reference then use `TEXTBEFORE()` and `XLOOKUP()` to do the job, to return the location.

Comment: You could add them to the [AutoCorrect](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/autocorrect-features-in-excel-8fd2dc2d-ca25-4b9b-88a5-fea044b2fa11) list.